# Как сделать редирект всего сайта и внутренних страниц?

Tags: .htaccess

```html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/wp-admin|.*wp-login\.php.*|/robots\.txt|/sitemap.xml|/googlsda1c.html|/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/sitemap.xsl) [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Главную редиректит но если зайти с old.com/ru/ то мы видит все содержимое. Как сделать полный редирект что бы в этом домене ничего не открывалось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?old.com(.+)?$ [NC]

Comment: ничего не изменилось. 
с главной перекидывает если что-то поставить после домена то ничего не происходит

Comment: Попробуйте еще как вариант вот так..
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?old.com[NC]

Comment: без изменений....